# How to Connect mobile with the pc

Tags: c#, winforms, mobile

I'm doing a desktop academic project one of the requirment of this project is to allert the user on mobile by sms and this sms should be sent by a mobile that is connected with the pc. I don't know the way how can i do it. When i did google search here i got the gsm modems gateways one kind of solution to send sms through pc. But they are not free. Then Nokia Conectivity SDK is another way but it is not compatible with Visual Studio2010. I got this example on a website but the  sender had said at the end there are errors in my code.

```
Option Explicit On

Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class form1



Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.load


End Sub


Private WithEvents SMSPort As SerialPort

Private SMSThread As Thread
Private ReadThread As Thread
Shared _Continue As Boolean = False
Shared _ContSMS As Boolean = False
Private _Wait As Boolean = False
Shared _ReadPort As Boolean = False
Public Event Sending(ByVal Done As Boolean)
Public Event DataReceived(ByVal Message As String)

Public Sub New(ByRef COMMPORT As String)
SMSPort = New SerialPort
With SMSPort
.PortName = COMMPORT
.BaudRate = 9600
.Parity = Parity.None
.DataBits = 8
.StopBits = StopBits.One
.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend
.DtrEnable = True
.RtsEnable = True
.NewLine = vbCrLf
End With
ReadThread = New Thread(AddressOf ReadPort)
End Sub

Public Function SendSMS(ByVal CellNumber As String, ByVal SMSMessage As String) As Boolean
Dim MyMessage As String = Nothing
'Check if Message Length <= 160

If SMSMessage.Length <= 160 Then
MyMessage = SMSMessage
Else
MyMessage = Mid(SMSMessage, 1, 160)
End If
If IsOpen = True Then
SMSPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=" & CellNumber & vbCr)
_ContSMS = False
SMSPort.WriteLine(MyMessage & vbCrLf & Chr(26))
_Continue = False
RaiseEvent Sending(False)
End If
End Function

Private Sub ReadPort()
Dim SerialIn As String = Nothing
Dim RXBuffer(SMSPort.ReadBufferSize) As Byte
Dim SMSMessage As String = Nothing
Dim Strpos As Integer = 0
Dim TmpStr As String = Nothing

While SMSPort.IsOpen = True
If (SMSPort.BytesToRead <> 0) And (SMSPort.IsOpen = True) Then
While SMSPort.BytesToRead <> 0
SMSPort.Read(RXBuffer, 0, SMSPort.ReadBufferSize)
SerialIn = SerialIn & System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(RXBuffer)
If SerialIn.Contains(">") = True Then
_ContSMS = True
End If
If SerialIn.Contains("+CMGS:") = True Then
_Continue = True
RaiseEvent Sending(True)
_Wait = False
SerialIn = String.Empty
ReDim RXBuffer(SMSPort.ReadBufferSize)
End If
End While
RaiseEvent DataReceived(SerialIn)
SerialIn = String.Empty
ReDim RXBuffer(SMSPort.ReadBufferSize)
End If
End While
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsOpen() As Boolean
Get
If SMSPort.IsOpen = True Then
IsOpen = True
Else
IsOpen = False
End If
End Get
End Property

Public Sub Open()
If IsOpen = False Then
SMSPort.Open()
ReadThread.Start()
End If
End Sub

Public Sub Close()
If IsOpen = True Then
'SMSPort = New SMSCOMMS("COM1")
'SMSEngine.Open()
'SMSEngine.SendSMS("919888888888", "SMS Testing")
'SMSEngine.Close()

SMSPort.Close()
End If
End Sub

End Class
```

but it is in vb.net i have not command in it. is it work?

Kindly Give me some idea, example I'm doing it in winform using c sharp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey i used GSMCOMM library and that works for me to send and receive sms using Computer. download it from google and see its examples to check how it works.
here are some links that help
[GSMCOMM Send and recieve SMS Using GSM Modem](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem)

[from here you can download GSMCOMM library](http://www.brothersoft.com/gsmcomm-for-.net-2.0-132883.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want a way to connect to a phone or a way to send an sms from a pc so I'll give both.

To connect to a phone (if it has data and an android or IOS or something where you can directly modify code) you can create a socket connection from your pc to your phone. I have done this in android aps before and it works good.

If you simply need to send an sms from your computer and you know the carrier just send an email using this list http://www.mutube.com/projects/open-email-to-sms/gateway-list/

Comment: But there is no name of my country in this list

Comment: ok try this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways, if not what country are you from then?